# Why does not this increase the way i want?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, get

I am writing a little in jQuery script that will print a month from a php-document:

```
    var count = 0;

$(".nextMonth").click( function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    count++;
    $("#result").load('index.php?month=' + count);
});

$(".prevMonth").click( function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    count--;
    $("#result").load('index.php?month=' . count);
});
```

I can get the index.php?month=1 without problem, but when i press the .nextMonth button again, it fails. I dont know what the problem is, I would appreciate som help! :)

Comment: There is no apparent reason why it wouldn't work. The `.prevMonth` handler has a `.` where it should have `+` though.

Comment: `.` concatenates strings in `php`, in `js` you should use `+`

Comment: What exactly do you mean by _it fails_? Does it fail with an error message (check JavaScript console)?

Answer (score 2):

I see an error in your syntax at the following line:

```
 $("#result").load('index.php?month=' . count);
```

You should use + instead of . so:

```
 $("#result").load('index.php?month=' + count);
```

Try this out maybe it will work

Comment: Oh, my PHP-fingers was a little bit to fast there... Thanks! Now I can go one stage back also, but then it fails again..

Answer (score 0):

Did you check in browser console about any errors in your code.

There is an error in your code. Please change to this:

This line :

```
$("#result").load('index.php?month=' . count);
```

should change to .

```
$("#result").load('index.php?month=' + count);
```

I can't find any other error. The complete code :

```
 var count = 0;

$(".nextMonth").click( function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    count++;
    $("#result").load('index.php?month=' + count);
});

$(".prevMonth").click( function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    count--;
    $("#result").load('index.php?month=' + count);
});
```

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: It's weird, when I click the next-button, the next month appears. If I click once more, the whole page freezes and chrome is near to crash, as if I started an infinity-loop.

Comment: Can you check the console for any error or what is the current call. I suggest better use firefox for checking the console calls...

Comment: Can you post the content of the result for your load call? do you load any javascript from there?

Comment: I checked the log in firefox and it seems that the first time, one request is sent, but the second time two requests is being sent, and so on... The third time, the script is requesting both month=1, month=2 and month=3

Comment: I think you are trying to load the entire page with the same scripts in it.. It will freeze the browser

Comment: I have found the problem! I was including the whole index.php page, as a result of that the js.js file was included again... I should of course had included the separate calendar-file only. Case closed! Thanks for the help! :)